# Creating pages dynamically through code?

Tags: 2013, master-page, page-layout, publishing-page, custom-masterpage

First thing is first, I'm doing this in Sharepoint 2013.

I'm not exactly sure what the best approach is to be, so I'm explaining my problem and hopefully people can throw around some terms or ideas that I can look up.

Basically we want to have a very cliched setup where there's regions/divisions and a project structure, so ultimately there's going to be Pages that represent a Project, a Project resides under a Region/Division.

Each project would have webpart sections displaying filtered data from a shared List, i.e. that List would have a Region/Division fields so that we can filter it down to those records to show on the Project.

But the issue here is I'll need to author a custom Administration Page that lets people generate a new Project on demand, and consequently it will create a new page.

Firstly I can't find much information with generating an actual Sharepoint Page dynamically through code, is this common or even possible?

Also, is it the correct way to author this Administration Page through the Sharepoint 2013 Designer?

Thank you in advance for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharePoint API : PublishingWeb (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.publishingweb_methods.aspx) with the method "AddPublishingPage"

if you need to customize this page after creation (i.e. add webparts on it), simply use SPWebPartManager (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.spwebpartmanager.aspx)

Using those APIs assume that your Web has the publishing feature activated.

hope that helps